# How to distinguish the indefinite article "un"/"une" from the cardinal number 1?

Tags: grammaire, articles

How to distinguish the indefinite article "un"/"une" from the cardinal number 1?

(a) *Jean mange **une** pomme tous les jours.* 'Jean eats an apple everyday'

(b) *J'ai **un** chat et deux chiens.* 'I have one cat and two dogs'

I can still see a difference between an indefinite article like in (a) and the cardinal number 1.
But the difference is very blurred in sentences like (b), and also when I compare directly (a) and (b).

Comment: je mange une pomme tous les jours  stays a number in my french mind, not indefinite. Indefinite could be 'je prends de la pomme tous les jours'

Comment: There's no such distinction in French. *Un* is both *a* and *one*. Languages differ from one another.

Comment: In English, **a** and **one** are often the same thing. Do you have *a* car? In French, une voiture. Whereas: in English we only say one when it's important to actually count the number of cars. "Yes, I have **a** car and **two** motorbikes. Only one? Yes, only one car. So: J'ai un chat et deux chiens. **can also be expressed as**: I have **a** cat and two dogs. Often, non-native English speakers will say: I have one cat, to mean "a cat".

Comment: @Lambie No, "a" and "one" are definitely different in English ; when you say "a" you do not say "one", properly you say "Yes, I have one car and two bikes.". "Yes I have a car" means "yes, I have some car". What you  infer subjectively from what you hear has nothing to do with the precise meaning of the word, which is not altered.

Comment: @LPH Pas si différents que ça. L'étymologie des articles *a* et *an* montre que ce ne sont que des variantes spécialisées de *one*. À l'instar des langues romanes, les autres langues germaniques ne distinguent d'ailleurs pas l'article indéfini du numéral *un* (ex: *ein* en allemand, *een* en néerlandais, *ett/enn* en suédois).

Comment: @jlliagre On ne s'occupe ici que des concepts modernes épurés des idées erronées que les anciennes langues ont nourries ou n'ont pas su éviter. Ce sont deux concepts bien distincts. Il y a une caractéristique commune, vrai,  le fondement sur l'idée d'unité, mais c'est tout, et l'idée essentielle dans l'indéfini est celle du caractère quelconque de la chose, qui manque totalement dans le concept du numéral.

Comment: @LPH Diantre, peu de langues ont su éviter cet écueil...

Comment: @LPH You did not understand what I said at all. You are wrong. I often hear beginning English speakers (who are French- or Spanish-speaking natives) say; I have **one** car, when they **actually mean**: I have a car. **In English, we only say "I have one car**" when the actual number of cars is not clear, and not in response to: As-tu une voiture? Oui or non. That is: Do you have **a** car? Yes or no? **And not**: *Do you have one car*. You might do me the honor of reading what I say more carefully...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, **the direction one is going in is important**:

**Going into French**:

- Do you have **a** car?
- Est-ce que tu as **une** voiture?
- Do you have **one car or two** cars?
- Est-ce que tu as **une** voiture ou **deux** voitures?
- Do you have **a** car or **a** motocycle?
- Est-ce que tu as **une** voiture ou **une** moto?

Conclusion: in French, a single item is always un/une because un/une **means *one* or *a***. So, basically you just need to get the masculine or feminine form of the article right. The English distinction of using "a" for one is irrelevant in French.

**Going from French into English:**

- Est-ce que tu as **une** voiture?
- The French can mean: Do you have **a** car? Do you have **one** car?

**Only the context will tell you which is meant.** For example:

- Tu as **une** voiture maintenant? Do you have **a** car now?
- Tu as **une** voiture maintenant? L'année dernière, tu en avais **deux**.
  Do you have **one** car now? Last year, you **had** two.

The other answers cover most of this but I just wanted to present it systematically.

Answer (score 3):

There is no fundamental difference between *un* singular undefinite article and the numeral *un*. In both cases, the count is still one.

There is only one apple eaten by Jean so it's more the numeral :

> *Jean mange une pomme tous les jours.* (Jean<sup>1</sup> eats one/an apple everyday)

Definitely the numeral:

> *Jean mange une pomme par jour.* (Jean eats one apple a day or even "an apple a day...")

Jean eats whatever apple, so it's more the undefinite:

> *Jean mange une pomme.* (Jean eats an apple.)

Jean eats a specific apple:

> *Jean mange la pomme*.

The following sentence doesn't make sense, Jean can't eat the same apple more than once:

> *Jean mange la pomme tous les jours.*

When using the plural, the distinction is obvious.

Two apples per day:

> *Jean mange deux pommes tous les jours.*

An unspecified amount of apples, this can be said even if Jean only eats one apple some days, or even everyday:

> *Jean mange des pommes tous les jours.*

With the cat and dogs example:

> *— Tu as combien de chats ? — J'ai un chat.* Clearly numeral.

> *— Tu as des animaux chez toi ? — J'ai un chat.* More undefinite but the number is still there.

> *— J'ai un chat et deux chiens.* I have one cat and two dogs.

<sup>1</sup> <sub>I usually prefer to translate *Jean* by John in this kind of examples.</sub>

Comment: The trick here is this: Jean mange une pomme par jour. We don't use the word "one" unless it is important in the context and is being compared to, say, two or three: I eat one apple a day, not two or three. **Generally, we say an apple**. I eat an apple a day. So, that's the scoop on "one" in English. It is very often just "a/an", unless actual count numbers are required. In fact, there is a famous saying: An apple a day keeps the doctor away.

Comment: @Lambie Oui, je suis d'accord avec la proximité de *a(n)* et *one*.  Off-topic: Je pense comprendre ce que tu veux dire avec "astuce" ailleurs en voyant ton *trick* ici. Je traduirait probablement ce *trick* par "truc" : *Le truc ici, c'est..."

Comment: @jlliagre Thank you. "There is no fundamental difference", I don't think it is what your answer really says in fact: there is a fundamental difference, it is just that sometimes it can be ambiguious.

Comment: @jlliagre I found a theoretical account on this fundamental difference in *Le Bon Usage* (p. 745) which goes as follows "*Un* est aussi numéral (§ 590). Quand il est article, on n'insiste pas sur le nombre (par opposition à *deux*, etc.), mais sur le fait que la réalité est imprécise. Si l'on veut marquer explicitement qu'il s'agit du numéral, on dit *un seul*. — Selon la remarque de M. Wilmet (dans *Langue fr.*, févr. 1983, p. 32), un numéral est nié par *pas un* ; un article par *aucun* ou *nul*. — L'anglais rend l'article par *a*, le numéral par *one*. Pour le latin, voir § 583, Hl."

Comment: @starckman LBU talks about a difference, but not a fundamental one. I suspect we only disagree because we are tied to our native language. In my opinion, *un* either lean toward a numerical meaning or toward an indefinite meaning, but that's not a fundamental difference. I don't feel there is any ambiguity. Consider the opposite situation where French consider there is a fundamental difference between *poil* and *cheveu* while English does not because the same word, "hair", is used for both.

Comment: @jlliagre In my understanding, the indefinite meaning and the numeral meaning are two fundamentally different things, and they are independent of French language, it is just that French language uses a same form (*un*) to express both, which can sometimes lead to ambiguity about whether *un* in that case expresses an indefinite meaning or a numeral meaning. This is illustrated by the fact that you can not say, I think, *Do you have **a** car or **two** cars?*

Comment: @starckman I still believe you consider it fundamental because of the English. I do not question the fact there is a conceptual difference, just that it is not fundamental because I'm convinced there are cases where it means both in French. No big deal. Would you say there is a fundamental difference between a beard hair and a a scalp hair?

Comment: @jlliagre "there is a conceptual difference", we agree on that. "there are cases where it means both in French", we don't agree on that. Concerning the example "*— Tu as des animaux chez toi ? — J'ai un chat.*", I don't agree with the statement  "More undefinite but the number is still there." The determinant that is used in the question is the indefinite *des* can be an indicator that *un* in the response is an indefinite. Because the article is in singular and because it is homophonous with the number 1, so it can give this impression that the article refers to a number.

Comment: Not only the impression in my opinion. *Un* does refer to the number too because that piece of information is provided by the reply. Otherwise, it would have been *— Oui, j'en ai.* We wouldn't reply *J'ai un chat* (with no more detail) if we have more than one.

Comment: @jlliagre We say *Oui, j'en ai* to substitute the noun by a pronoun. "We wouldn't reply J'ai un chat (with no more detail) if we have more than one." This is because *un* is singular.

Comment: Precisely, "singular". The reason why I still say no fundamental difference. *[MWD](https://www.merriam-webst) Singular: of, relating to, or being a word form denoting **one** person, thing, or instance.*

Comment: @jlliagre Ok, now I better understand your points "there is a conceptual difference, just that it is not fundamental" and "More undefinite but the number is still there."

Answer (score 1):

There is  a fundamental difference between the singular undefinite article  and the numeral "one" in French, of course. As there is no difference in the graphical *form* of these two concepts, the only way to distinguish them is the context, and at times (perhaps, more often than not) it is confusing, not clear.

- Une voiture est arrivé par cette route. (*There is not enough context, there is no possibility of telling.*)
- — Combien y a-t-il de véhicules dans ce lot ?
  —  J'ai vu qu'il y a une voiture…  (*Here again, it is not clear what the second person might be saying; is it the communication of a thought dissociated from the idea of number? Is the person really the person saying that there is at least one car? You don't really know. The more careful speaker will be aware of the difficulty and modify his sentence consequently, as below.*)

— J'ai compté une voiture. (*It's clear, one car.*)
— Comme j'ai vu une voiture, il y a au moins un certain nombre de voitures. (*undefinite article; however it does take some thinking in order to ascertain that.*)

In truth, the lack of two forms for these concepts  in French is a pain in the neck.

Comment: Do you have **a car**? Yes or no? As-tu **une voiture**? Oui ou non.

Comment: @Lambie Soyez claire, qu'est-ce que ça veut dire ça ? Rien !

Comment: Est-ce que tu as enseigné l'anglais? J'ai essayé deux fois de te l'expliquer mais cela ne semble pas t'intéresser.

Comment: @Lambie Il ne faut pas dire n'importe quoi, même si vous avez de la colère. Parlez du problème, c'est mieux.

Comment: Tu ne fais que des commentaires moralisants. Moi, j'essaie de te parler de la langue.